# Partial Template Specialization using enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, type-traits

I am trying to understand how to use type traits with std::enable_if to "enable" partial specializations of a class.  Here is the example code I am attempting to get workingL

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

class AbstractFoo {
public:
    virtual const char* name() const = 0;
};

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class Foo;

template <>
class Foo<int> : public AbstractFoo{
public:
    const char* name() const override { return "int"; }
};

template <>
class Foo<char> : public AbstractFoo {
public:
    const char* name() const override { return "char"; }
};

template <typename T>
class Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type> : public AbstractFoo {
public:
    const char* name() const override { return "enum"; }
};

enum class MyEnum {
    VAL1,
    VAL2,
    VAL3
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> v1;
    Foo<char> v2;
    Foo<MyEnum> v3;
    
    std::cout << "v1.name()=" << v1.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v2.name()=" << v2.name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "v3.name()=" << v3.name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
};
```

My goal is to have specific specializations for certain types (e.g., int and char), but, if the type is an enum, to use my partial specialization.  However, when I attempt to compile this code, I get the following error

> error: aggregate 'Foo v3' has incomplete type and cannot be
> defined

Which I assume means my specialization was not chosen and thus never becomes defined.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have too much inside enable_if. Remove «, T» and everything work as intended.

Comment: .. and if you use C++17 or later you can simplify it into: `class Foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum_v<T>>> : public AbstractFoo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the declaration of `Foo` the second template parameter defaults to `void`. That means that the following variable:

```
Foo<MyEnum> v3;
```

is actually

```
Foo<MyEnum, void> v3;
```

Now the question is: does this correspond to the specialization you want? Not really, because in your specialization for enum:

- `std::is_enum<T>::value = true` when `T = MyEnum`
- `std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, T>::type = T = MyEnum`
  when `T=MyEnum`

So, for `T=MyEnum`, your give the specialization for `Foo<T, T>`, which does not match the variable above.

As noted in a comment, a simple fix is to declare the specialization as

```
class Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type>
```

In this way, the second template parameter is `void` when `T=MyEnum`, so it matches the variable declaration of `v3`.